# looking for a C# mocking framework that allows mocking static methods

Tags: c#, mocking

i am required to quickly learn a mocking framework that allows mocking static methods and write test cases for an application written in C#. which framework would you recommend?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it using the following frameworks:

1. [Typemock Isolator](http://site.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product/)
2. [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx)
3. [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) (You can only stub the methods, you can't assert them).

Example of faking a static method using Isolator:

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => MyClass.MethodReturningZero()).WillReturn(1);
```

*Disclaimer - I work at Typemock*

Comment: -1 for only linking your own product... Find JustMock here:
http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx and Moles here: 
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/